# IDW succeeded but not visible in table of contents

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, inverse-distance-weighted

I used now several times ArcMap 10.7.1 and until now everything worked quite well. For my Masters Thesis I have to work with IDW to interpolate my datas. It worked all the time. Now, I run the IDW with the same dataset and results told me it was successful but it is not visible in Table of Contents and on the map I cannot explain why and what the problem is. Maybe someone is able to help me out of this trouble.

Comment: A common problem is having too long a filename (cannot have more than 10 characters, I think, if it's stored outside a geodatabase).  If you can find the output in your geoprocessing history but cannot right-click>add to display, then restart the program and try again.

Comment: So my filname is short, just three latter's.. You explained it quite well, if appears in the history but not in the table of content and click add to display does not worked. So I restarted it and it's still the same. Maybe my Computer is the problem? Ot any other ideas?

Comment: Where have you saved the output? Is it in the Geodatabase / Folder, what happens if you navigate and look in that location? Try changing the output location and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed now arcmap on another Computer and the problem still exists... The output folder is still the home - document/Arcgis folder where all the other rasters exists. And as I said at the beginning the interpolation works and I am able to see them. But Now the raster is not visible in the folder but Idw results show me that the process is succeeded. Someone has the same problem or an idea?? I AM TOTALLY LOST :(

Comment: Another possibility -- and this is more of a stretch -- is that there is a projection issue going on.  It's possible that you opened a different file first in the dataframe, and now you are working in a different projection than previously.  Check the dataframe coordinate reference system under its properties and compare the CRS of your layer (properties>source).  Your best bet for interpolating is probably a local projection: state plane or national grid, rather than WGS84.

Comment: It's also possible your points are somehow corrupted.  Can you get a fresh copy?  If you used Display XY, did you remember to export the events layer and use that in the IDW tool?